# Fisher Vector with LSH?

Tags: c++, image-processing, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, sift

I want to implement a system where given an input image, it returns a reasonable similar one (approximation is acceptable) in a dataset of (about) 50K images. **Time performances are crucial**.

I'll use a parallel version of SIFT for obtaining a matrix of descriptors `D`. I've read about Fisher Vector (FV) ([VLfeat](http://vision.princeton.edu/pvt/align2RGBD/align2RGBD/lib/vlfeat/doc/overview/encodings.html) and [Yael](http://yael.gforge.inria.fr/tutorial/tuto_imgindexing.html) implementations) as a learning and much more precise alternative to Bag of Features (BoF) for representing `D` as a single vector `v`.

My question are:

1. What distance is used for FVs? Is it the Euclidean one? In that case I would use LSH in eucledian distance for quickly find approximate near neighbor of FVs.
2. There is any other FV efficient (in terms of time) **C++** implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method you could take into consideration is *VLAD* encoding. (Basically a non-probabilistic version of FV, replacing GMMs by k-Means clustering)

Implementation differs only slightly from standard vector quantisation, but I my experiments it showed much better performance with significantly lower codebook size.

It uses euclidean distance to find the nearest codebook vector, but instead of just counting elements, it accumulates every elements *residual*.

An example for image search: [Link](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/pubs/2010/JDSP10/jegou_compactimagerepresentation_slides.pdf)

FV / VLAD paper: [Paper](https://hal-univ-rennes1.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/633013/filename/jegou_aggregate.pdf)

Comment: From what I understand by your answer (very useful btw, thanks!), VLAD are better than FV, which surprises me since I thought that FV were an improvement of VLAD. That's a good thing, since I didn't understand GMMs completeley. Anyway, what about using LSH for E2 distances (like [FALCONN](https://falconn-lib.org/)) for finding the ANN? Last thing: what implementations of VLAD/FV have you used?

Comment: I wrote my own implementation based on the given paper. I used OpenCVs BFMatcher to do the matching, but you could replace that part by anything else. Code is in C++

Comment: Of course this is going to be implementation dependent, but VLAD approach is going to be more expensive than BoF one?

Comment: I haven't benchmarked it (yet), so I can't really say.

Comment: Could you please give me some reference for a VLAD implementation in C++? I don't know if yours is available, in that case would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You could take a look at my implementation in my [spare time project](https://github.com/s1hofmann/pipeline_framework/tree/master/src/pl/core/encoding)